# Dumb recomposition in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

Consider this minimal code snippet (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            var time by remember {
                mutableStateOf("time")
            }
            Column(modifier = Modifier.clickable { time = LocalDateTime.now().toString() }) {
                Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                Text(text = time)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Examining the above code, from a logical perspective, one expects that upon clicking the `Column`, since only the parameter `time` changes, only the lower time `Text` composable would be redrawn. This is because [recomposition skips as much as possible](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#skips).

However, one finds that the upper `Text` composable is being redrawn too (the displayed UUID keeps changing).

1. Why is this?

Notice that the non-idempotence of my `Column` composable should have no bearing unless the redraw is dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running this block of code

```
@Composable
fun IdempotenceTest() {    
    var time by remember {
        mutableStateOf("time")
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            time = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = getRandomUuid())
        TestComposable(text = returnSameValue())
        Text(text = time)
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestComposable(text: String) {
    SideEffect {
        Log.d(TAG, "TestComposable composed with: $text")
    }
    Text(text = text)
}

private fun getRandomUuid(): String {
    Log.d(TAG, "getRandomUuid: called")
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}

private fun returnSameValue(): String {
    Log.d(TAG, "returnSameValue: called")
    return "test"
}
```

If you check the logs, you will see that everytime the state changes, the compiler tries to re-call the smallest enclosing lamda/function where the state's value is being read. Hence, the IdempotenceTest function (in my example and setContent{} lamda in yours) will get re-executed which will call the `getRandomUuid` and `returnSameValue` function and based on the value returned by these, it will decide whether or not to re-compose the elements which depend on these return values. If you want to prevent a calculation from happening again and again, wrap it in a `remember{}` block.

Now if you were to use a `Button` for example instead of a Column, you would have seen that only the content lamda of the same would have been executed. The reason why this happens is that Column is an inline function while Button in itself uses Surface inside it which is non-inline. Therefore the content of `Column{}` is copied inside the enclosing function block thus leading to the entire `IdempotenceTest` being invalidated for re-composition.

As a side-note, the Composable functions must be side-effect free to ensure idempotence. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#simple-example).

To read more about recomposition scope, you can refer to the blog posts [here](https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78) and [here](https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose).

Comment: "everytime the Column recomposes"..that is the essence of the question...why is the entire Column recomposing in the first place?

Comment: "the compiler will call the getRandomUuid..." why? shouldn't only code observing `time` be recalled by compiler?

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain more information about recomposition scopes.

Comment: that Zach post really clears things up..thnx

Answer (score 0):

`rememberSavable {...}` worked for me.

It allows you to update the state, directly from `clickable` and trigger recomposition:

```
...
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
...

var time by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("time") }
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { 
        time = LocalDateTime.now().toString() 
    }
) {
    Text(text = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    Text(text = time)
}
```